# react firebase auth not recognizing when user is signed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication

In my react app in the header it checks if the user is signed in or not. The issue is that it thinks there is no user signed in even when there is. This wasn't a problem when I had a single page app, only now is it an issue.

Header:

```html
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

import React from 'react'
import SignIn from "./SignIn";
import SignOut from "./SignOut";

function Dropdown() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    return (
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            {user.displayName}
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/profile">My facts</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Admin</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
            <li><SignOut class="dropdown-item btn btn-link text-dark" /></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    )
}

function Header() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const handelSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  return (
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cool Cow Facts</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="./">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                            Submit Fact
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                    <form onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            { user ? <Dropdown /> : <SignIn class="btn btn-link nav-link active text-dark" message="Sign In" /> } 
                        </ul>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Hi, if you’re sending the user to a new page, you need to use firebase.auth.onstatechanged (check out the google documentation) to recognize that the user already logged in.

Comment: FYI, it only works if the new page is part of the same subdomain.

Comment: @sychordCoder Thanks this fixed the issue of not recognizing the user being logged in but now for the dropdown function it cant figure out the user.displayname